# converting array value to string writable to text file incoming from $_GET function

Tags: php, arrays, get

No matter what I have tried nothing solve my problem
a php file receiving content with defined variables like that

```
<?php
$user_id=$_GET["user_id"];
$platform=$_GET["platform"];
$devicemodel=$_GET["devicemodel"];
$deviceuuid=$_GET["deviceuuid"];

--------
and then

$content =$content. " ".$user_id;
$content =$content. " ".$platform;
$content =$content. " ".$devicemodel;
$content =$content. " ".$deviceuuid;


$file = "activities.log"; 
file_put_contents($file, $content);


?>
```

When I see the content of activities , I always see 
Array()Array()Array()Array()

No matter, what I tried to change the array type to string or text by using
* implode ,var_export, print_r  functions

I always see the Array()Array()Array()Array() written inside the created log file.
When I write the echo $content; It seems realy fine.

What am I missing ? IS there anyone experienced the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: or why not just `$content = "$userid $platform $devicemodel $deviceuuid";`, make sure they are strings, not an empty array.

Comment: Do `var_dump($_GET)` and add that to your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, if they are indeed strings, quite odd to see `Array()`'s on the written file. a sample query string or `$_GET`'s var_dump should clarify this

Comment: Serkan, how are you pulling in those values, from a form or other method? If so, make sure you're not using a POST method in it. I need more information to give you a better answer and show us how you're using it, if from an `href` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I realized that only using the **json_encode** function solved my problem and started to turn the array json data to a string format which file_put_content works .
Here you can  the working complete code for me. Btw there was not any problem with concatenation using the lines $content=$content."" it sill works.

```
<?php 

$content ="--başlık--".json_encode($_GET["title"]);
$emails="--email--".json_encode($_GET["user_email"]);
$tarih="--tarih--".json_encode($_GET["tarih"]);
$categori= "--kategori--".json_encode($_GET["kategori"]);
$picturename="--picturename--".json_encode($_GET["picturename"]);
$username="--username--".json_encode($_GET["username"]);
$user_id="--userid--".json_encode($_GET["user_id"]);
$platform="--platform--".json_encode($_GET["platform"]);
$devicemodel="--devicemodel--".json_encode($_GET["devicemodel"]);
$deviceuuid="--deviceuuid--".json_encode($_GET["deviceuuid"]);


$content =$content." ".$tarih;
$content =$content." ".$emails;
$content =$content. " ".$user_id;
$content =$content. " ".$username;
$content =$content. " ".$categori;
$content =$content. " ".$platform;
$content =$content. " ".$devicemodel;
$content =$content. " ".$deviceuuid;
$content =$content. " ".$picturenam;
$file = "/*******/public_html/testupload/logs/logs-tarih-".date("Ymd").".log"; 

$content ="date---".date("F j, Y, g:i a")."--".$content."\n";
//file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);

$fp=fopen($file,"a");
fputs($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You will need to provide us with the method that you are using your code, if in a form, or via an `href` method.

However, the answer I have given below is only partially correct. The rest will depend on you to provide us with the way you are using it.

Otherwise, I will delete this answer.

---

#### Original answer

You're constantly overwriting `$content =$content` on each pass.

So, you need to concatenate it `$content .=$content` but not for the first.

This is what I tested this with, and with success:

```
<?php

$_GET["user_id"] = "ID";
$_GET["platform"] = "Platform";
$_GET["devicemodel"] = "Model";
$_GET["deviceuuid"] = "UUID";

$user_id= $_GET["user_id"];
$platform= $_GET["platform"];
$devicemodel= $_GET["devicemodel"];
$deviceuuid= $_GET["deviceuuid"];

$content =$content. " ".$user_id;
$content .=$content. " ".$platform;
$content .=$content. " ".$devicemodel;
$content .=$content. " ".$deviceuuid;

$file = "activities.log"; 
file_put_contents($file, $content);

?>
```

You may also want to add `\n` after each line written, otherwise it will end up as one long line, if that's what you want as a result.

Edit:

As per what Ghost said in a comment, using:

```
$content = "$user_id $platform $devicemodel $deviceuuid";
```

instead of all those additional variables.

Comment: This is not why OP gets `"Array()"`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck You have a point there, and I was thinking the same thing earlier. Maybe OP is taking it from a form, and is using the wrong method? I'll ask the OP.

Comment: Or their form is like `?user_id[]=value&...`

Comment: @Ja͢ck Could be. I've asked the OP to provide more information. Will wait and see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs fine for me. Try this and see if you still have the same issue:

```
<?php

$_GET["user_id"] = "user_id";
$_GET["platform"] = "platform";;
$_GET["devicemodel"] = "device_model";;
$_GET["deviceuuid"] = "device_uuid";;

$user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
$platform = $_GET["platform"];
$devicemodel = $_GET["devicemodel"];
$deviceuuid = $_GET["deviceuuid"];

/*
and then
*/


$content = $content. " ".$user_id;
$content .= " ".$platform;
$content .= " ".$devicemodel;
$content .= " ".$deviceuuid;


$file = "activities.log"; 
file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

If this works for you, then the problem is your code. If this doesn't work for you, then it's your PHP installation.

Edit: Fred just beat me to it!

Comment: *"Edit: Fred just beat me to it!"* - Actually, I had posted a comment first and deleted way before I posted my answer lol which is why I did that after testing it out first.

Comment: "If this doesn't work for you, then it's your PHP installation." - substituting `$content = $content . ' ' ... etc `with the equivalent `$content .= ' ' ...` doesn't really change much and I highly doubt it has anything to do with the installation itself.